# Proxy protocol error in apache logs of my virtaul host

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, httpd, httpd.conf

I have a two virtual hosts on three linux servers behind an ELB. I have enabled proxy protocol for my ELB so that the requests for ssl are terminated on instance rather than on ELB. I am seeing following errors very continuously in my one of the virtual host logs

### Error log:

```
[Thu Oct 19 14:57:07.126415 2017] [proxy_protocol:error] [pid 2992] [client 127.0.0.1:47348] ProxyProtocol: no valid header found
[Thu Oct 19 14:57:07.471596 2017] [proxy_protocol:error] [pid 3076] [client 127.0.0.1:47388] ProxyProtocol: no valid header found
[Thu Oct 19 14:57:07.785776 2017] [proxy_protocol:error] [pid 3076] [client 127.0.0.1:47428] ProxyProtocol: no valid header found
[Thu Oct 19 14:57:07.909984 2017] [proxy_protocol:error] [pid 2528] [client 127.0.0.1:47450] ProxyProtocol: no valid header found
[Thu Oct 19 14:57:08.384383 2017] [proxy_protocol:error] [pid 2612] [client 127.0.0.1:47496] ProxyProtocol: no valid header found
```

### Access logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:45 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:45 +0000] "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:45 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:45 +0000] "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:45 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:46 +0000] "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:46 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:46 +0000] "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2017:14:57:46 +0000] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-"
```

Could you please suggest on how to eliminate these errors. These errors are started very recently and before I didnt find any of these errors. I dont see any such errors in my QA environment.

### Edit:

[ELB health check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRfWx.png)

Comment: what does your ELB health check look like?

Comment: Below is my prod ELB health check:

Ping Target 
TCP:443
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval 6 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 2
Healthy threshold 3

For QA I dont see any such errors, only for prd i see those. 
I have also attached the ELB health check to the question

Comment: I checked with AWS support team and they confirmed that everything is fine at ELB level and proxy protocol is also enabled. These errors are very frequent like I am receiving them like 5 of those for every second. Not sure what are causing these errors so suddenly @Mike